# TensorFlow CMake build on windows10

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, cmake, windows-10

i have tried to install tensorflow with CMake on win10 and followed this Step-by-Step instruction: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/395cfc42ee3c5842f5383f4049674c012998b133/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md#step-by-step-windows-build

At point 2 i had the problem that the folder contrib in the path ..\tensorflow\tensorflow not exists. I have create the folders ..\contrib\cmake\build and changed the directory. The instruction says i should only create the build-folder.

At point 3 i became a CMake error because there is no "CMakeLists.txt" in the source directory. (Source directory is one folder above -> ..\contrib\cmake)

My Question now is whether i have doing something wrong?
And maybe anyone can help me or send me the missing CMakeLists.txt file.

If something is not clear you are welcome to ask me.

***Edit1:***

I have changed the branch in the repo and found the correct files. Now I try to build it with CMake and get the following error:

CMake Error at tf_core_ops.cmake:37 (add_library):
No SOURCES given to target: tf_losses
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:201 (include)

I have searched in the web for any solutions, but I don't find one.

It seems like there is missing the "losses.cc" file in this folder: '[tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/395cfc42ee3c5842f5383f4049674c012998b133/tensorflow/core/ops)'

***Edit2:***

A solution for Edit1 was to comment out the losses in the *.cmake-files. Maybe this is a really bad Idea, but the configuration and generation process run successfully.
Now I have the next problem and I have absolutely no idea how to fix it.

The Building process with MSBuild is failed with the following 11 errors:

```
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_cc_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_lib.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\eigen.vcxproj" (default target) (6) ->
(CustomBuild target) ->
  CUSTOMBUILD : error : downloading 'https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/9569d1f35bae.tar.gz' failed [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\eigen.vcxproj]
  CUSTOMBUILD : The requested URL returned error : 404 [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\eigen.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4444266cbc571315a47f1
9d224fa07de\eigen-download.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4444266cbc571315a47f19d224fa07de\eigen-update.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4444266cbc571315a47f19d224fa07de\eigen-pa
tch.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4444266cbc571315a47f19d224fa07de\eigen-configure.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4444266cbc571315a47f19d224fa07de\eigen-build.rule;V:\tensorfl
ow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4444266cbc571315a47f19d224fa07de\eigen-install.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4d20a30288788c3317be273c56e4b7ba\eigen-complete.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contr
ib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\2360a698abcad2f7699a444432cb8f34\eigen.rule' exited with code 1. [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\eigen.vcxproj]


"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_cc_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_lib.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\gemmlowp.vcxproj" (default target) (10) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\e42ad724cfa8f30e9851d
2c4b08eb10c\gemmlowp-download.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\e42ad724cfa8f30e9851d2c4b08eb10c\gemmlowp-update.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\e42ad724cfa8f30e9851d2c4b08eb10c\ge
mmlowp-patch.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\e42ad724cfa8f30e9851d2c4b08eb10c\gemmlowp-configure.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\e42ad724cfa8f30e9851d2c4b08eb10c\gemmlowp-build.r
ule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\e42ad724cfa8f30e9851d2c4b08eb10c\gemmlowp-install.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4d20a30288788c3317be273c56e4b7ba\gemmlowp-complete.rule;V:\tensor
flow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\2360a698abcad2f7699a444432cb8f34\gemmlowp.rule' exited with code 1. [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\gemmlowp.vcxproj]


"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_cc_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_lib.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\grpc.vcxproj" (default target) (14) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\protobuf.vcxproj" (default target) (15) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xtree(1601,1): error C3848: expression having type 'const google::protobuf::compiler::java::`anonymous-namespace'::FieldDescriptorCompare'
 would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'bool google::protobuf::compiler::java::`anonymous-namespace'::FieldDescriptorCompare::operator ()(const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor *,const google::protobuf::FieldDescri
ptor *)' [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\protobuf\src\protobuf\libprotoc.vcxproj] [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\protobuf.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xtree(1591,1): error C3848: expression having type 'const google::protobuf::compiler::java::`anonymous-namespace'::FieldDescriptorCompare'
 would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'bool google::protobuf::compiler::java::`anonymous-namespace'::FieldDescriptorCompare::operator ()(const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor *,const google::protobuf::FieldDescri
ptor *)' [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\protobuf\src\protobuf\libprotoc.vcxproj] [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\protobuf.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3a6c5208e6ab500d63031
a50eb6272e5\protobuf-update.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3a6c5208e6ab500d63031a50eb6272e5\protobuf-patch.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3a6c5208e6ab500d63031a50eb6272e5\proto
buf-configure.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3a6c5208e6ab500d63031a50eb6272e5\protobuf-build.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\3a6c5208e6ab500d63031a50eb6272e5\protobuf-install.ru
le;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4d20a30288788c3317be273c56e4b7ba\protobuf-complete.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\2360a698abcad2f7699a444432cb8f34\protobuf.rule' exited with code
1. [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\protobuf.vcxproj]


"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_cc_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_lib.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg_copy_headers_to_destination.vcxproj" (default target) (20) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg_create_destination_dir.vcxproj" (default target) (21) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg.vcxproj" (default target) (22) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\29537cbbb7e7b1a684e44
bf862af002a\jpeg-download.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\29537cbbb7e7b1a684e44bf862af002a\jpeg-update.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\29537cbbb7e7b1a684e44bf862af002a\jpeg-patch
.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\29537cbbb7e7b1a684e44bf862af002a\jpeg-configure.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\29537cbbb7e7b1a684e44bf862af002a\jpeg-copy_jconfig.rule;V:\tensor
flow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\29537cbbb7e7b1a684e44bf862af002a\jpeg-build.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\29537cbbb7e7b1a684e44bf862af002a\jpeg-install.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\
cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4d20a30288788c3317be273c56e4b7ba\jpeg-complete.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\2360a698abcad2f7699a444432cb8f34\jpeg.rule' exited with code 1. [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\b
uild\jpeg.vcxproj]


"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_cc_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_framework.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_lib.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png_copy_headers_to_destination.vcxproj" (default target) (24) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png_create_destination_dir.vcxproj" (default target) (25) ->
"V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj" (default target) (26) ->
  CUSTOMBUILD : error : downloading 'https://storage.googleapis.com/libpng-public-archive/libpng-1.2.53.tar.gz' failed [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  CUSTOMBUILD : The requested URL returned error : 404 [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\306f7040ab2b8351b3103
44321db5faf\png-download.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\306f7040ab2b8351b310344321db5faf\png-update.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\306f7040ab2b8351b310344321db5faf\png-patch.ru
le;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\306f7040ab2b8351b310344321db5faf\png-configure.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\306f7040ab2b8351b310344321db5faf\png-build.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorf
low\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\306f7040ab2b8351b310344321db5faf\png-install.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\CMakeFiles\4d20a30288788c3317be273c56e4b7ba\png-complete.rule;V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build
\CMakeFiles\2360a698abcad2f7699a444432cb8f34\png.rule' exited with code 1. [V:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
```

Two of them are errors because a link does not work. Maybe the other ones are consequential errors.
But what should I do, if the link is down?
There should be a file with that link to change them?

Comment: ***At point 2 i had the problem that the folder contrib in the path ..\tensorflow\tensorflow not exists. I have create the folders ..\contrib\cmake\build and changed the directory.*** You can't just create an empty folder.

Comment: I think you cloned the folder wrongly with your git  application if you missed this folder because it exists right here: [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/395cfc42ee3c5842f5383f4049674c012998b133/tensorflow/contrib/cmake](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/395cfc42ee3c5842f5383f4049674c012998b133/tensorflow/contrib/cmake)

Comment: @drescherjm only in that specific branch that folder exists. 
In the master it don't.

Thank you, i try to clone the specific branch.